# Resolve "InvalidOperationException: The LINQ expression [...] could not be translated" and keeping the ToListAsync()

Tags: c#, asp.net, linq, asp.net-core, ef-core-3.0

In EF Core 3.x LINQ queries that cannot be translated are no longer evaluated on the client. From what I understand it means that it cannot process code that can't directly be translated to SQL.

---

In my case I want to use the foreach(PropertyInfo in type.GetProperties()) to evaluate each component of a class.

```
private static bool stringInMovement(Movement m, string toTest)
{
    foreach(PropertyInfo component in typeof(Movement).GetProperties())
    {
        try {
            if (component.GetValue(m).ToString().ToLower().Contains(toTest.ToLower()))
                return true;
        }
        catch { }

    }
    return false;
}
```

And then use this in a where statement :

```
movements = movements.Where(m=> stringInMovement(m, SearchString));
```

I want to keep the result a IQueryable because after the function it's in is an async Task and the last line is

```
Movements = await movements.AsNoTracking().ToListAsync();
```

I would like to keep the all function as asynchronous and I don't want to have to write a where statement with 10x m.Component.Contains(searchstring). It's to search for a specific element of a database by the way.

Thank you for your help !

The error I get when trying to search for something :

> ```
>     Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.QueryableMethodTranslatingExpressionVisitor.<VisitMethodCall>g__CheckTranslated|8_0(ShapedQueryExpression translated, ref <>c__DisplayClass8_0 )
>     Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.QueryableMethodTranslatingExpressionVisitor.VisitMethodCall(MethodCallExpression methodCallExpression)
>     Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.RelationalQueryableMethodTranslatingExpressionVisitor.VisitMethodCall(MethodCallExpression methodCallExpression)
>     System.Linq.Expressions.MethodCallExpression.Accept(ExpressionVisitor visitor)
>     System.Linq.Expressions.ExpressionVisitor.Visit(Expression node)
>     Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.QueryCompilationContext.CreateQueryExecutor<TResult>(Expression query)
>     Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Storage.Database.CompileQuery<TResult>(Expression query, bool async)
>     Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.Internal.QueryCompiler.CompileQueryCore<TResult>(IDatabase database, Expression query, IModel model, bool async)
>     Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.Internal.QueryCompiler+<>c__DisplayClass12_0<TResult>.<ExecuteAsync>b__0()
>     Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.Internal.CompiledQueryCache.GetOrAddQueryCore<TFunc>(object cacheKey, Func<Func<QueryContext, TFunc>> compiler)
>     Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.Internal.CompiledQueryCache.GetOrAddQuery<TResult>(object cacheKey, Func<Func<QueryContext, TResult>> compiler)
>     Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.Internal.QueryCompiler.ExecuteAsync<TResult>(Expression query, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
>     Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.Internal.EntityQueryProvider.ExecuteAsync<TResult>(Expression expression, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
>     Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.Internal.EntityQueryable<TResult>.GetAsyncEnumerator(CancellationToken cancellationToken)
>     System.Runtime.CompilerServices.ConfiguredCancelableAsyncEnumerable<T>.GetAsyncEnumerator()
>     Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.EntityFrameworkQueryableExtensions.ToListAsync<TSource>(IQueryable<TSource> source, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
>     Intuo.IndexModel.OnGetAsync() in Index.cshtml.cs
>     +
>                 Movements = await movements.AsNoTracking().ToListAsync();
>     Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.RazorPages.Infrastructure.ExecutorFactory+NonGenericTaskHandlerMethod.Execute(object receiver, object[] arguments)
>     Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.RazorPages.Infrastructure.PageActionInvoker.InvokeHandlerMethodAsync()
>     Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.RazorPages.Infrastructure.PageActionInvoker.InvokeNextPageFilterAsync()
>     Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.RazorPages.Infrastructure.PageActionInvoker.Rethrow(PageHandlerExecutedContext context)
>     Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.RazorPages.Infrastructure.PageActionInvoker.Next(ref State next, ref Scope scope, ref object state, ref bool isCompleted)
>     Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.RazorPages.Infrastructure.PageActionInvoker.InvokeInnerFilterAsync()
>     Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.<InvokeNextResourceFilter>g__Awaited|24_0(ResourceInvoker invoker, Task lastTask, State next, Scope scope, object state, bool isCompleted)
>     Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.Rethrow(ResourceExecutedContextSealed context)
>     Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.Next(ref State next, ref Scope scope, ref object state, ref bool isCompleted)
>     Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.InvokeFilterPipelineAsync()
>     Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.<InvokeAsync>g__Awaited|17_0(ResourceInvoker invoker, Task task, IDisposable scope)
>     Microsoft.AspNetCore.Routing.EndpointMiddleware.<Invoke>g__AwaitRequestTask|6_0(Endpoint endpoint, Task requestTask, ILogger logger)
>     Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authorization.AuthorizationMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext context)
>     Microsoft.AspNetCore.Diagnostics.DeveloperExceptionPageMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext context)
> ```

Comment: Can you try AsEnumerable()?

Comment: If I do that I can't use the asynchronous method unfortunately

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you want is to dynamically generate an `Expression<Lambda>` to use in the where clause.

```cs
        public static Expression<Func<T,bool>> ContainsString<T>(string value)
        {
            var constValue = Expression.Constant(value);
            var parameter = Expression.Parameter(typeof(T), "p");

            return Expression.Lambda<Func<T, bool>>(
                typeof(T).GetProperties()
                    .Where(p => p.PropertyType == typeof(string))
                    .Select(p => (Expression)Expression.Call(
                        Expression.Property(parameter, p), 
                        "Contains", 
                        new Type[] { typeof(string) },
                        constValue))
                    .Aggregate((a, c) => Expression.OrElse(a, c)),
                parameter);
        }

        movements = movements.Where(ContainsString<Movement>(SearchString));
```

Answer (score 1):

EF/EF Core can not translate anything that involves reflection, or more complex logic into SQL. Instead of this, there are several ways to achieve what is required - to write all props in a query:

```
movements = movements
    .Where(m => m.Property1.ToString().ToLower().Contains(SearchString.ToString().ToLower() &&
                m.Property2.ToString().ToLower().Contains(SearchString.ToString().ToLower() /* ... */ );
```

Or build specific `Expression` which would be passed as argument into `.Where` via custom [Expression Visitor](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.expressions.expressionvisitor?view=netframework-4.8) or with method:

```
public static Expression<Func<Movement, bool>> CompareToStr(string searchString) 
{
    Expression res = null;
    var param = Expression.Parameter(typeof(Movement), "x");
    foreach (var component in typeof(Movement).GetProperties())
    {
        // building the expression to get a property
        var arg = Expression.Property(param, component.Name);
        // now we have `x.Property1` expression

        var toStrCall = Expression.Call(
                // to what expression we applying the .ToString method
                arg,
                // link to 'ToString', 
                // needed to be altered, if it would be used in non-sql runtime as if there are nullable types with `null` values, this would cause NRE at runtime
                component.PropertyType.GetMethod(nameof(object.ToString), new Type[] { }));
        // now we have `x.Property1.ToString()` (watch out NRE)

        var toLowerCall = Expression.Call(
            toStrCall, 
            typeof(string).GetMethod(nameof(string.ToLower), new Type[] { }));

        // now we have `x.Property1.ToString().ToLower()`
        var containsCall = Expression.Call(
                toLowerCall,
                typeof(string).GetMethod(nameof(string.Contains), new[] { typeof(string) }),
                Expression.Constant(searchString.ToLower())); // since arguments of expression tree should be the expressions
        // here we passed the constant string expression, so now we have
        // x.Property1.ToString().ToLower().Contains( value of testString.ToLower())

        if (res == null)
        {
            res = containsCall;
        }
        else
        {
            res = Expression.Or(res, containsCall);
        }

        // after several iterations it has
        // x.Property1...Contains(testString) || x.Property2...Contains(testString) and so on
    }

    return Expression.Lambda<Func<Movement, bool>>(res, param);
    // and result x => x.Property1... || x.Property2 ...
}
```

(I have not tested this code). So the goal is to create the instance of [Expression Tree](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/concepts/expression-trees/) and pass it as argument to `.Where` call. This way EF/EF Core will be able to translate it into SQL, as it knows how to translate `.ToString()` calls and `.ToLower()` calls:

```
movements = movements.Where(CompareToStr(SearchString));
```

Comment: @Matomatt `ToString` method is defined in the `object` class, so it should be possible to call `ToString` on string instance, as string inherits object. Also, edited the answer to get the definition of the correct ToString method.

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer ! It works well except if the component is a string because it doesn't have the "ToString()" method, it also doesn't work with booleans for some reason even though they have the ToString() method. I just added some condition and it works well, thank you again !

Comment: It should be possible but it doesn't  ¯\\_(ツ)_/¯